# Proving some sup over integrals is finite (could we exchange $\sup$ and $\int$?).

Tags: analysis

Could someone help me to prove that $$I=\sup_x \int_{|x-y|<1}|q(y)|^2 \omega(x-y) \, dy <\infty$$ where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $q(y)$ is bounded for all $y$ and $\omega(x-y)$ is a function given by: $\mathbf{i})$ negative powers of $|x-y|$, e.g., $|x-y|^{-1}$ or $\mathbf{ii})$ $\omega(x-y)=\log |x-y|$ or $\mathbf{iii}$ $\omega(x-y)=1$?

What about to exchange supremum and integral?

Comment: But negative power is not defined in this domain!

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal Not real clear on your comment.

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal, in fact, you're right, thanks for your reply. That's is why i) is false as proved by zhw bellow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i) is false:  On $\mathbb R^1,$ take $q \equiv 1,\omega (x-y) = 1/|x-y|.$ For $x=0$ we get $\int_{-1}^1 1/|y|\, dy = \infty.$

ii) is true for obvious reasons: The integrand is $\le 0$ on the region of integration.

If you want to know the absolute value of the integral is bounded independent of $x,$ you can argue this way: Suppose $|q|\le M.$ Then the absolute value of the integral is bounded above by

$$\int_{|x-y|<1} q^2(y) |\ln |x-y|| \, dy \le M^2\int_{|x-y|<1} |\ln |x-y|| \, dy = M^2\int_{|y|<1} |\ln |y|| \, dy <\infty.$$

Ask if you have questions on why the last integral is finite.

iii) True, and it's very simple.

Comment: zhw, thank you for that!

Comment: I have a question about your answer. In ii), Why could you use $\int_{|x-y|<1} q^2(y) |\ln |x-y|| \, dy$ (that is, the first integral that you wrote in ii)), instead of that I've defined in the question? Note that you put the absolute value $|\ln |x-y||$, instead of $\ln |x-y|$. Can this be done?

Comment: @R.Ferreira  I'm using $|\int f| \le \int |f|.$

Comment: I got the idea! Thank you once. You've really, really, helped me.

Comment: You're certainly welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely less than infinity, its producing a real number. So therefore its definitely true. However, if it was something like $$I=\sup_x \int_{|x-y|<1}{|q(y)|^2 \omega(x-y) \, dy >\infty}$$ it'd be false.

Also, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \inf (f_n)  = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup (f_n) = f$

Its LIMITING to infinity, therefore it's not necessarily infinity. :)

Comment: I don't understand a single sentence in your answer.

Comment: @Verideth, anyway, thanks, I'll think about!

Comment: No problem @R.Ferreira :)